# Jogl Shader programming

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, shader

I just started Shader programming(GLSL) and created a few with RenderMonkey. Now I want to use this Shaders in my java code. Are there any simple examples of how I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a very simple example

```
int v = gl.glCreateShader(GL.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
int f = gl.glCreateShader(GL.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

BufferedReader brv = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("vertexshader.glsl"));
String vsrc = "";
String line;
while ((line=brv.readLine()) != null) {
  vsrc += line + "\n";
}
gl.glShaderSource(v, 1, vsrc, (int[])null);
gl.glCompileShader(v);

BufferedReader brf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fragmentshader.glsl"));
String fsrc = "";
String line;
while ((line=brf.readLine()) != null) {
  fsrc += line + "\n";
}
gl.glShaderSource(f, 1, fsrc, (int[])null);
gl.glCompileShader(f);

int shaderprogram = gl.glCreateProgram();
gl.glAttachShader(shaderprogram, v);
gl.glAttachShader(shaderprogram, f);
gl.glLinkProgram(shaderprogram);
gl.glValidateProgram(shaderprogram);

gl.glUseProgram(shaderprogram);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any myself, but if I have a problem along these lines I have often found the best place for 3D programming and Java advice is over at [JavaGaming.org](http://www.javagaming.org/) - I've not been there for a while, but it was always a helpful and knowledgeable community.

Answer (score 3):

The new version of Jogl adds as an Utility shader loading/compiling and Uniform setting/getting calls. Have a look at the [API](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/glsl/package-summary.html) for the selection of methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [ogre4j](http://ogre4j.sourceforge.net/), a Java wrapper/port of the popular open-source [Ogre3D](http://ogre3d.org/) graphics engine. It might be a bit heavy-weight for your needs, but for a proper 3D project, worth a look for sure.