# OpenGL Shader Compilation Errors: unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"

Tags: c++, opengl, error-handling, compilation, glsl

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400985/opengl-shader-compilation-issue-unexpected-eof) question and it really shedded some light. Despite this, I can't seem to figure out how I'm "improperly" loading my shader, because this *has* executed before without any recent changes to the shader loading code, so I assume these errors must be coming from my draw calls.

Despite this, I'll still post the shader files for the sake of brevity, the draw function used to draw the circle I'm trying to render, and the code which loads in the shader file as a string.

Basically what I need to know is why I'm getting these errors and what in the hell is wrong with them?

(*From debug output*)

```
ERROR { 
    OpenGL Says: 
     Vertex info
-----------
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"

Fragment info
-------------
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"

 };
```

**Draw Code**

```
    void Circle::draw( GLuint program )
    {
        const size_t centerMag = mCenter.length();

        glUseProgram( program );

        for( float t = 0; t < mCircumference; t += 0.1 )
        {
            float x = centerMag + glm::cos( 2 * M_PI * t );
            float y = centerMag + glm::sin( 2 * M_PI * t );

            mVertices->push_back( glm::vec4( x, y, 0, 1 ) );
        }

        QListIterator< glm::vec4 > iVertices( *mVertices );

        const size_t size = mVertices->size();

        float** verts = new float*[ size ];

        size_t i = 0;

        glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

        while( iVertices.hasNext() )
        {
            verts[ i ] = new float[ size ];
            verts[ i ] = const_cast< float* >( glm::value_ptr( iVertices.next() ) );

            glVertexPointer( 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts[ i ] );

            glDrawArrays( GL_LINES, 0, 4 );

            ++i;
        }

        glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

        for( unsigned iMem = 0; iMem < size; ++iMem )
        {
            delete[] verts[ iMem ];
            verts[ iMem ] = NULL;
        }

        delete[] verts;
        verts = NULL;
    }
```

**FileUtility**

```
    QString FileUtility::readShader( QString filepath )
    {
        std::ifstream in( filepath.toStdString().c_str() );
        std::stringstream shaderDat;

        shaderDat << in.rdbuf();

        QString shaderFile;

        shaderFile += shaderDat.str().c_str();

        in.close();

        return shaderFile;
    }
```

**GenericColor.frag**

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputColor;

void main()
{
    outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
}
```

**Position.vert**

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

**Update**

Since my shader binding/compilation code was requested, I figured I may as well just post my entire shader handler, as well as the engine class.

-[Engine](http://pastebin.com/h2HMTxFx)
-[ShaderHandler](http://pastebin.com/cVjJS03s).

**Update**

Here are the shader strings parsed (`Info` is a debug output):

```
Info { 
    Shader Source #version 330

in uniform mvp;

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix = mvp;
    gl_Position = position;
}




 };



Info { 
    Shader Source #version 330

out vec4 outputColor;

void main()
{
    outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
}


 };
```

Comment: Could you also show the shader compilation/VA binding code ?

Comment: Updated, I decided to pastebin the entire source file.

Comment: Any chance you could post the exact c_str's that are getting loaded to glShaderSource? Shader compilation errors shouldn't have anything to do with the rest of the program (your draw code there is likely irrelevant). Maybe could spot something that way.

Comment: Yup, just updated. I am wondering if the problem is because I'm using Qt though for this...

Comment: Oh, Qt... The QGLWindow might not be the thing that support the GL3.1 core profile... Unfortunately. You'll have to hack a little to create a compatible context using pure WinAPI. You didn't tell about Qt, but this is rather a well-known issue with GL3

Comment: I'm actually on Linux, but I figured I may as well just use this:
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_(GLX)

Comment: Yes, the GLX is almost the same.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That error message means that the shader compiler is seeing a garbage character (something other than a printable ASCII character, a space, a tab, or a newline) on the first line of the shader.  Which most likely means that the string you're passing to `glShaderSource` is garbage -- probably a dangling pointer that once pointed at your shader code but no longer does due to something getting destructed.

**edit**

I see from your link you have code that looks like:

```
s.Source = shader.toStdString().c_str();
```

That will set `s.Source` pointing at the internal buffer of a temporary `std::string` object that will be destroyed shortly after this line, leaving `s.Source` a dangling pointer...

Comment: THANK YOU. God, sometimes I hate the fact that I came from a C# background.

Comment: Another case note: This happened with me too, but with **missing \0 terminator at the end**, so I'm adding this to your statement saying **"on the first line of the shader"**.

Comment: @Wappenull: A missing NUL will generally give you that error on the *last* line of the shader rather than the first.  The number in parenthesis at the beginning of the error message is the line number (The number before the paren is the index in the array passed to glShaderSource)

Answer (score 2):

My guess: I've seen the glLoadMatrix() calls in your code which  basically means you're using an outdated (pre-3.1) GL API and do not initialize the GL3.1 Core Profile context correctly.

This leads to the situation where your context does not support the GLSL1.50+ and the "location" attributes (thus the error from shader compiler).

Try changing the initialization of GL and then check the [glBindAttribLocation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml) calls. Avoid using the glLoadMatrix stuff - use shader uniforms instead.

Look at opengl.org's site: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_(C%2B%2B/Win)  for a GL 3.1 context creation sample. It is a little different from GL2.0-

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not related to your current problem, but will be one soon enough :

```
verts[ i ] = new float[ size ];
verts[ i ] = const_cast< float* >( glm::value_ptr( iVertices.next() ) );
```

The memory allocated in the first line is leaked, moreover, when you call `delete` a few lines  after, you're deleting the value given by `new` but the casted one. Is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I cut, and paste some shader code from a website. I assume the difference in LF/CR was causing the problem. Removing the pasted text with the same code manually typed in worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this error in Standard C by forgetting to put the `NUL`(`\0`) terminator at the end of the `malloc`'d memory where I was reading the characters into.

<s>I suspect GL looks for the null termination character in order to link the shaders during `glLinkProgram()`(glew).</s>

If you don't pass the `const GLint *length` parameter to `glLinkProgram()`  [it assumes NUL termination.](https://docs.gl/gl3/glShaderSource) hence the error. Thanks to [derhass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327517/derhass) for pointing this out.

Comment: "I suspect GL looks for the null termination character " Only if you tell it to. You either specify the lenght of each string part via the `length` parameter of `glShaderSource`, or you use negative lenghtes or `NULL` for the whole `length` array to tell itthat the strings are NUL-terminated.

Comment: You're totally right! My brain completely glossed over the documentation for the length** param.