# What is the meaning of the parameters to glShaderSource?

Tags: opengl, c++

I've tried my hardest to understand the functions of OpenGL in-depth, but I have an issue with `glShaderSource`'s parameters:

```
void glShaderSource(
  GLuint shader,
  GLsizei count,
  const GLchar * const * string,
  const GLint * length);
```

I'm confused about the last two parameters. What do they actually mean in C++? Does it mean I give it a string, a const char or pointer of a string if thats even possible? And why?

Answer (score 39):

`glShaderSource` expects two related sequences (C-style arrays) of values.

The first sequence is an array of C-strings, either zero-terminated or not.

The second sequence is an array of integers, indicating the length of each of the strings in the first sequence. This sequence is optional if the strings are zero-terminated, as the library will find the lengths by itself.

The GL-prefixed types are because the OpenGL specification needs to talk about types without tying itself into a particular language, so it introduces aliases of common C types.

`GLchar` is a type similiar to the C `char`, which serves to represent a narrow character.
`GLint` is a signed integer type, commonly used to represent object handles and offsets.
There's also others like `GLenum` and `GLvoid`.

`GLchar const*` is the OpenGL spelling of the `char const*` type. Apart from being used to point to a single character, it's commonly used to represent a string of characters. When used in that meaning, it shall point to a sequence of characters, ending with a sentinel value `'\0'` to know that the string ends.

The reason for making `glShaderSource` take more than one string is because OpenGL's shader compiler has exposed the concept of a *file*. Each of these strings represents the contents of one *file*, and it will compile as if these *files* are concatenated together. Note that this *file* is largely unrelated to the filesystem thing of the same name. `glShaderSource` only deals with strings containing text.

This is beneficial when you've got some fragments you want to assemble together into the full shader source, like if you want to prepend a `#version` statement or some common preamble, or have implemented some sort of include directive yourself.

As for an example of how to use it:

```
std::string v = "#version 150\n";
std::string c = ReadTextFile("common.glsl"); // read a string with the file contents
std::string s = ReadTextFile("mesh.vert");   // same here

GLchar const* files[] = { v.c_str(), c.c_str(), s.c_str() };
GLint lengths[]       = { v.size(),  c.size(),  s.size()  };

glShaderSource(id, 3, files, lengths);
```

Here we're combining three strings for OpenGL to consider as one large chunk of source text. Note that my convenience function `ReadTextFile` reads the content of a filesystem file into a string, no part of OpenGL ever touches the filesystem. If you want to get the contents of a text file, image file or mesh file into OpenGL structures, you need to read it in for yourself ahead of time.

Comment: Fantastic Answer Lars Viklund but would it be possible to explain it if you was using a .vert or .frag file instead of just strings and obscure gl data types that I've hardly used though this is very useful it's not in the right context I guess you could call it that!

Answer (score 14):

Let's go through this step by step:

- `const GLchar` is an immutable (constant) character.
- `const GLchar *` is a pointer to immutable `GLchar`s, in this case your shader source.
- `const GLchar * const` is an *immutable* pointer to immutable `GLchar`s, that means the pointer itself can not be changed to point somewhere else.
- `const GLchar * const *` is a pointer to an immutable pointer to immutable `GLchar`s.
- Finally `string` is just the name of the parameter.

That means it expects a pointer to a constant pointer to constant `GLchar`s. You can use it like so (using NULL for the size, to let `glShaderSource` figure out the lengths):

```
const GLchar *source = "my awesome shader";
glShaderSource(myShader, 1, &source, NULL);
```

Or to specify more than one source:

```
const GLchar *sources[] = {
  "my awesome shader",
  "another awesome"
};
glShaderSource(myShader, sizeof(sources)/sizeof(*sources), sources, NULL);
```

I haven't actually tested the above code and there may be some casts necessary, but it should show how it works in principle.

Comment: Interesting immutable means what exactly?

Comment: Basically it means that something can't be changed. In this case the glShaderSource promises to neither change the pointers you give it or the shader sources they point to.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering how to read a (shader) file into a string to pass to `glShaderSource()`. But this is not even necessary.

The OpenGL docs (khronos.org) say:

> If length is NULL, each string is assumed to be null terminated.

From which follows: the "string" does **not** have to be **null terminated**, but then you have to pass the correct **length**.

The command lets you pass more than one of these string/length pairs - that is the `count` parameter. Lars' answer has a good example.
Here is the body of my function to read a shader file into a *unterminated* string. It is in C, quite simple and direct without any copying, just a `open()`, `fstat()` and `mmap()`. Only takes a bit of fiddling with the types, because I have `count=1` and no extra array variables.

```
int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    printf("Error opening shader file %s", filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Normally I don't care too much about errors, but a filename can always be wrong, and the following commands would not like an fd of -1 or the results thereof...

---

```
struct stat stb;
fstat(fd, &stb);
```

This is to get the length (string length = file size).

---

```
const char *mm = mmap(NULL, stb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
```

`mm` now points to the start of the string. `mm` *is* the string, period. But the end is not defined(?), we only know the length. `mm[stb.st_size] = '\0'` does not work, because of...different reasons.

---

```
close(fd);
```

Can be done after `mmap()`.

---

Instead of assigning `mm` (the address) into a one-sized array, I pass `&mm`:

```
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &mm, (int *)&stb.st_size);
```

Similar for the length/st_size; only here the value is inside a struct. Looks a bit scary. This is how `fstat()` and `glShaderSource()` collide. And gcc compiler: you can actually leave out the `(int *)` cast at the cost of a compiler warning.

Also `void *mm = mmap(...)` works, but produces an (instructive) warning.

The compiler needs both: the `&` and the correct types. The second `const` can be left out, at least.

Even replacing `(int *)&stb.st_size)` with `NULL` and ***hoping*** for null termination works in my case. A shader file of exactly 4096 bytes might be needed to provoke an error. Or some other kind of (in this case) well-deserved bad luck.

---

This I neglected - right after `glShaderSource()` has copied from `mm`, you can:

```
 munmap((void *)mm, stb.st_size);
```

So the correct type of `mm` does not really pay off, because it has to be recast back to prevent a warning...maybe just leave it `void *mm` and do the whole **array-of**-(pointer-to)-something job with the function parameters.

```
glShaderSource(shader, 1, (const char **)&mm, (int *)&stb.st_size)
```

---

On the other hand, with two extra arrays and four extra lines, most casts, stars and ampersands disappear:

```
const char *mm_arr[1];      // array of one (string aka char pointer)
mm_arr[0] = mm;             // first and only element is set; no cast needed even if 'void *mm'
int sz_arr[1];              // array of a single int
sz_arr[0] = stb.st_size;    // normal assignment of int to int

glShaderSource(shader, 1, mm_arr, sz_arr);
```

### And why?

For **flexibility** - as if they thought (quite long ago!): These programmers might well read in their shader files with getline() or so, so let us not force them to merge the lines and/or null terminate them. They can pass it as they have it.

**Not** to specify more than one shader (as the other A suggests), but to specify one shader in more than one parts (lines or logical parts).

---

Here is a C++ example I found, doing quite exactly the same (but with null termination, not size):

```
fstram.open(shaderPath);    
sstream << fstram.rdbuf();
fstram.close(); 

id = glCreateShader(type);

auto data = sstream.str();
const char* dataPtr = data.c_str();

glShaderSource(id, 1, &dataPtr, NULL);
```

There is `fstram.rdbuf()` and `sstream.str()` and `data.c_str()`. This is not really much simpler. One way or the other, there is some run up until you can pass that `&dataPtr` pseudo array.

(The name `dataPtr` is very...defensive)

---

Official specs:

> const GLchar ****string**
>
> **string**
>
> Specifies an array of pointers to string**s** containing the source code to be loaded into the shader.

I prefer:

strings -- specifies an array of char pointers. These strings contain...

This might seem trivial, but after "slurping" in the whole file into one string, you wonder about this plural, or array of, or pointer to, or ampersand.

---

I see only `slang/vstest.c` in `mesa-demos` using size:

```
  f = fopen (filename, "r");
   if (f == NULL)
      return;

   fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
   size = ftell (f);

   if (size == -1) {
      fclose (f);
      return;
   }

   fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);

   code = (char *) (malloc (size));
   if (code == NULL) {
      fclose (f);
      return;
   }
   size = fread (code, 1, size, f);
   fclose (f);

   glShaderSourceARB (vert, 1, (const GLcharARB **) (&code), &size);
```

I prefer `fstat()` and `mmap()`, and `(const char **)&code`.

Comment: Welcome! I know virtually nothing about this subject, but I'm struggling to see how this answers the question?

Comment: It is about passing the contents of a file to the GPU-RAM. See Rose's comment on Lars' good A. "... if you was using a .vert or .frag file instead of just strings and obscure gl data types". So I show how to read in a file, and not an artificial array of three strings. "this  subject": you are not talking about pointers and arrays in C I guess. And deduce the rest you cannot?

Comment: Q is asking about const GLchar ** ("obscure") so I simplify to char and explain why it has two stars and show different ways to pacify the compiler. This must translate 99% to C++.

Comment: @josephkibe This is very related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400985/opengl-shader-compilation-issue-unexpected-eof