# OpenGL requires a "const char", but I have to read it from file

Tags: c, opengl, types

I'm creating a **C** header to load my shaders from a file, instead of how I was doing before, that was something like this:

```c
const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";
```

That way, I could just set my shader as a `const` and it worked. But now I wanna make it read from a separate file, so I created this header:

```c
#define ASSERT(x, str) if (!(x)) {printf(str); exit(1);}

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef int32_t i32;

uint shader_create_program(char vertex_path[], char fragment_path[]) { 
  // Vertex shader
  FILE* file = fopen(vertex_path, "r");
  i32 success;

  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  int size = ftell(file) + 1;

  char vertex_shader_source[size];
  fread(vertex_path, sizeof(char), size, file);
  vertex_shader_source[size] = '\0';
  fclose(file);

  uint vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertex_shader_source, NULL);
  glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

  glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
  ASSERT(success, "Error compiling vertex shader");

  // Fragment shader
  file = fopen(vertex_path, "r");

  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  size = ftell(file) + 1;

  char fragment_shader_source[size];
  fread(fragment_shader_source, sizeof(char), size, file);
  fragment_shader_source[size] = '\0';
  fclose(file);

  uint fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragment_shader_source, NULL);
  glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

  glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
  ASSERT(success, "Error compiling fragment shader");

  // Create shader program
  uint shader_program = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(shader_program, vertex_shader);
  glAttachShader(shader_program, fragment_shader);
  glLinkProgram(shader_program);
  glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
  glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);

  glGetProgramiv(shader_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
  ASSERT(success, "Error linking shaders");

  glUseProgram(shader_program);

  return shader_program;
}
```

---

Which is giving me errors, because `glShaderSource` third parameter is expected to be a `const char`.

I tried just setting it constant, but obviously, it can't be in this case, as I have to manipulate it.

The problem can be found in this snippet:

```c
  char vertex_shader_source[size]; // Initialize the source here
  fread(vertex_path, sizeof(char), size, file); // I have to read the file into the buffer
  vertex_shader_source[size] = '\0'; // And also add the end char
  fclose(file);

  uint vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertex_shader_source, NULL); 
  // Then, here it was expecting for a constant value
```

---

If my shader code is needed: (*vertex-shader.glsl*)

```c
# version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aCol;

out     vec4 _color;

uniform vec4 uniform_color;

void main() 
  gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1);
  _color = vec4(aCol, 1);
}
```

Error message:

`expected ‘const GLchar * const*’ {aka ‘const char * const*’} but argument is of type ‘char (*)[size]’`

Comment: The compiler message is not particularly about `const char` or whether anything is `const` or not. The message is about passing a pointer to an array when a pointer to a pointer is expected.

Comment: guys, I tried some weird things here, and it seems I'm getting close. If I set it as a constant pointer, it can be changed
`const char*`
But then the error is mismatching type for param
`EXPECT const char * const* | RECEIVE const char * (*)[size]`

Comment: a well, it's what you said then

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of the parameters to glShaderSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22100408/2505965) - specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22100409) covers the topic well, IMO. e.g., make an array of pointers to strings `const GLchar *sources[] = { vertex_shader_source };` and pass that along `glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, sources, NULL);`.

Comment: I got this, but, since the `char` is required to be imutable, is it impossible to make it from files? The tutorial I was following was using CPP, and the just done it like `const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();`

Comment: Eric, can you make this as an answer, just so I can close it. And thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot speak to the semantics since I do not work with OpenGL, but to get the desired type, you can use `& (const char *) { vertex_shader_source }` for the argument, as explained below.

The compiler message indicates the expected type is `const char * const *`. The last `*` means it wants a pointer. The last `const` does not mean the pointer actually has to be `const` when it is defined, just that the `glShaderSource` routine will not change it. So you can create a pointer for this without having to make the pointer `const`.

That pointer is supposed to be a pointer to `const char`. Again, the `char` elements that are pointed to do not have to be defined as `const`; we just need a pointer to them with that type. We can create a pointer to the first element of `vertex_shader_source` by using a compound literal: `(const char *) { vertex_shader_source }`. (You could also use a variable: `const char *TemporaryPointer = vertex_shader_source;`.)

Then you merely need to pass the address of this pointer to the routine: `& (const char *) { vertex_shader_source }` or `&TemporaryPointer`. The `&` produces a pointer of type `const char * *`, and the implicit conversion to the parameter type will add a `const`, making it `const char * const *`.